# Adding a CSV with GPS coordinates points and bathymetry data to Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, table, bathymetry, importerror

I'm trying to construct a bathymetry point map on GEE, and I want to import a CSV that contains bathymetry data.
The CSV that I'm about to import to GEE has the following columns: Latitude, Longitude and Depth.

I uploaded my data:
[image]

And I set the advanced settings as the following:
[image]

However, whenever I try to import the data, the following message shows up:

> The table may not have valid geometries

[image]

the lat and lon becomes a floating point value, and the depth becomes 256 in all the rows. In addition, there is an additional column added to the table.

I cannot use this data for my analysis, and I would like to ask if anyone could help!

The CSV can be accessed from the following link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cY86-r84u2OPfoKkO5ODBXfbosRamrGV/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of your file has some UTF junk in it:

```
<U+FEFF>Latitude,Longitude,Depth
```

Remove that first character and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you s much! it worked fine :)

Comment: @Joji Please consider accepting this answer by selecting the green check mark so we can consider this question resolved.